# displaying image and text within the same DIV through content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-content

I am creating a print CSS for IE browser, within which I have to add text and an image in a div through CSS.
I am using `content` to add text and `background` to add an image, but somehow Image is not being shown.

This is how I'm doing.

```
#header .container:after { 
        content:  "@The_Text_after_Twitter_Logo";
        background: url("../path_to/logo-twitter.png");
        position:absolute; 
        width:999em; 
        height:25px; 
        margin:0 0 0 5px; 
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Am I doing it wrong somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`:after` is a empty pseudo-class in IE, meaning it comes with no pre-defined box-model and you'll need to give it some display.

```
display: block;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: sadly, it didn't help Jamie.

Comment: can you whack up an example? maybe a JS fiddle?

Comment: I created a JFiddle and it works there :/ but it doesn't work in IE8's print review. :(

Comment: Are you using a print style sheet? `@media print { … }`

Comment: Yes. It's for the print.